# What's this error from a simple db unit test of Yii?

Tags: yii

```
root@u1010:/opt/lampp/htdocs/trackstar/protected/tests# phpunit unit/DbTest.php
PHPUnit 3.4.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) DbTest::testConnection
CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.

/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:275
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:242
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:221
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/base/CModule.php:363
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/framework/base/CModule.php:86
/opt/lampp/htdocs/trackstar/protected/tests/unit/DbTest.php:6

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
root@u1010:/opt/lampp/htdocs/trackstar/protected/tests#
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the 'db' component declaration in protected/config/test.php

This configuration file is used when you're running your tests.

Check protected/tests/bootstrap.php to see the included files.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  After about half a day of pulling my hair out. This is all I had to do. Hope it helps others.  Several simple checks solved this issue.  I've got multiple copies of both php and phpunit with different paths.  I'm assuming you have your /requirements/index.php checks passed, and your config/main & test files set.

1. In terminal locate your PHPUnit executable:

   which phpunit
2. Locate your running php executable:

   which php
3. sudo vi path/to/phpunit  (the executable)
4. make sure that the first line referencing the php exectuable is actually the one from step two.

Solved my headache.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It could not connect to your database.  Either:

- Your database connection settings are incorrect.
- Your database is not running.
- There is a networking misconfiguration.

Comment: config/main.php: 'db'=>array(

'class'=>'CDbConnection',
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=trackstar_dev',
'emulatePrepare' => true,
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '123456',
'charset' => 'utf8',
),

Comment: Make sure you can connect using those creds to that db from both the MySQL client and using mysql_connect in PHP.

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("trackstar_dev") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";
!!this script pass

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "123456") or die (mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL";
```

sometimes the privileges setting for the MySQL server are different for "127.0.0.1" and "localhost". If this is the case, you can do:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON trackstar_dev.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
```

on your mysql server

Comment: or you could change your yii main.php into ...,'connectionString'=>'localhost',...